# Phonegap: Access existing playlists from Android mediastore?

Tags: android, cordova, mediastore, playlists

Does anybody know how I would access the android MediaStore.Audio.Playlists area from within phonegap? Is this at all posible? I am looking to add a simple media player to my existing app.

I have searched the phonegap media documentation - and have a media player playing audio files within the phonegap asset area, but I cant find a way to retreive existing playlists from the device.

Cheers

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this problem? It looks like PhoneGap does not provide a plugin to access the media library... The only alternative I've found so far is to use Appcelerator [Titanium.Media.Item](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.Item)